# java.sql.SQLException : Not a Wrapper of OracleConnection.class in Tomcat 9.0 Version

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Using SpringMVC wit JDBC Template and tocmat 9.0 version and Oracle DB and jar file ojdbc6.jar file java1.8 version, the application is throwing an exception by saying

java.sql.SQLException:  Not a wrapper of oracleConnection.class

```
in tomcat conf/context.xml

<Resource name="jdbc/db" auth="Container" 
 type="javax.sql.DataSource"  
 accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed="true"
 factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
  username="USER" password="password" maxTotal="20" maxIdle="10"  
   maxWaitMillis="-1" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" url="URL" />
```

I am using following line in my code   to use

```
OracleConnection conn= jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection().unwrap(OracleConnection.class);

ArrayDescriptor des=ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("XXX",conn);

at this point it throwing the error getting null , unable to fix the issue any help is appreciated.
at this point it it throwing the error , unable to fix the issue anyhelp is appreciated.
```

Comment: Use the debugger to see what actual connection class is wrapped by the connection you are getting from your data source.

Comment: And why do you want to unwrap it?